# Magento 2: How to show USPS shipping method at first sort order?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

How to change the sorting order of the following shipping methods in order to keep the prioritize **USPS** And **UPS**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to set sort order for shipping method ?

Comment: @user55548 How to sort any idea. with jquery

Comment: In magento admin Store -> Configuration -> Sales(left menu) -> Shipping Method. On this page you can find Sort Order textbox for every shipping method

Comment: @user55548 Thankyou so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement, you can use the sorting procedure. You can get this through the Magento admin panel.

**In Magento admin Store -> Configuration -> Sales(left menu) -> Shipping Methods -> Choose your desired shipping method and give the sort order.**

You can find the Sort Order textbox for every shipping method. By giving the low valued numbers, you can get your requirement.